What's the reason for the following error:Use of 'subGoal' refers to instance method rather than class 'subGoal' in module 'Goal_Calendar'
One view is shared between the main app and its widget. In this view, an error shows 'Use of 'subGoal' refers to instance method rather than class 'subGoal' in module 'Goal_Calendar'.  Use 'Goal_Calendar.' to reference the class in module 'Goal_Calendar'. The code lines showing the error are as following.
 for subgoal in subGoals {
                        subGoalID = goalID + "subGaol" + UUID().uuidString
                        let goal = subGoal(subGoalID: subGoalID, subGoalDescription: subgoal.subGoalDescription, subGoalColorName: goalColorName, subGoalStartDate: subgoal.subGoalStartDate, subGoalEndDate: subgoal.subGoalEndDate, subGoalAchievedDate: subgoal.subGoalAchievedDate, isAchieved: subgoal.isAchieved, subGoalAchievedPhotos: [])
                        modelContext.insert(goal)
                        try? modelContext.save()
                    }

I add Goal_Calendar in the codes based on the error as following:
for subgoal in subGoals {
                        subGoalID = goalID + "subGaol" + UUID().uuidString
                        let goal = Goal_Calendar.subGoal(subGoalID: subGoalID, subGoalDescription: subgoal.subGoalDescription, subGoalColorName: goalColorName, subGoalStartDate: subgoal.subGoalStartDate, subGoalEndDate: subgoal.subGoalEndDate, subGoalAchievedDate: subgoal.subGoalAchievedDate, isAchieved: subgoal.isAchieved, subGoalAchievedPhotos: [])
                        modelContext.insert(goal)
                        try? modelContext.save()
                    }
                    

But a new error appears. The error is "Cannot find 'Goal_Calendar' in scope". What's the reason for it? How to debug it.

How about renaming the class (not the instance method) subGoal to SubGoal? Class names should be PascalCase.

It works! Really thanks, Sweeper!
